# Keyboard hides TextField - Flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard, widget

I've made a chat page that contains the header, a `MessagesStream` and a `Row` that includes the `TextField` and `RaisedButton`. I've checked every single page there is about this issue, both in GitHub and StackOverflow, but I wasn't able to find any solution. The row does not go up when the keyboard is launched, instead it goes over the bottom part of the screen, hiding everything.

Could anyone please help me figure this out? I've literally tried everything.

This is my `Scaffold`:

````
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, color: Colors.white),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Image(
            image: iconApp,
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Material(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                        color: grayWhite,
                        elevation: 2,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:10),
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 15),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Image.network(
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 15),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Test",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black54,
                                            fontSize: 20
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3, left: 15),
                                      child: Text(
                                       "Test2",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black54,
                                            fontSize: 15
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: 1,
                                      color: Colors.white70,
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      MensagensStream(),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: textEditingController,
                                autofocus: true,
                                autocorrect: true,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  mensagem = value;
                                },
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                    ),
                                    hintText: "Digite a sua mensagem..."
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ButtonTheme(
                            height: 55,
                            minWidth: 10,
                            child: RaisedButton(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                    100,
                                  )
                              ),
                              color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                              child: Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.white),
                              onPressed: () => {
                                textEditingController.clear(),
                                firestore.collection('mensagens').add({
                                  'Mensagem': mensagem,
                                  'Remetente': googleEmail,
                                  'Destinatario': "patio@teste.com",
                                  'DataHorario': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                                })
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap either one of you `Column`s (probably the outer one) with a `SingleChildScrollView`. The issue is that simply popping up the keyboard doesn't suddenly tell the layout that it needs to be able to scroll. You have explicitly say you want it to be able to scroll.

See [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) for more information on the `SingleChildScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Scaffold` and place the text field as `bottomSheet`